# Why does python3-config list -ldl before the last lined library?

Tags: python

Running `python2.7-config --libs`, `python3.5-config --libs`, etc. results in the following output:

```
-lpython<version> -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

Why isn't libdl the last linked library? I believe the order only matters when the preceding libraries reference the latter, but do neither libutil nor libm reference libdl, but libpthread does? I am unable to examine libpthread the way I normally might (readelf and/or nm) as it is apparently not in the right format.

Comment: I am able to examine /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 and have found several calls starting with `_dl` (_dl_allocate_tls...) However, none of these are the expected dlopen, dlclose, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the later libraries appear to reference libdl, so linking to libdl first is unnecessary. In fact, linking to libdl *first* appears to have no effect, nor does skipping it entirely.

```
#include "Python.h"
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {}
```

...

```
gcc -o main main.c `python3.5m-config --cflags` -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lutil -lm
```